# iTextPDF (Version 5) hyperlink not linking to the right place

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, tableofcontents

I have bunch PDFs that I have merged at this point of Code. At the start of the merged PDF, there is a Table of Content Section that I am generating. Now, the TOC acts as a bookmark and clicking on that should take me to correct page. However, if I click on the link , it jumps to between the bottom of the page and the next page.

I have this code:

`action = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("p" + entry.getKey(), false); link = new PdfAnnotation(copydoc, 36, ct.getYLine(), 559, y, action); stamp.addAnnotation(link);`

However, I have also created bookmark in the PDF that works fine .
[Bookmarks example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doMSa.png)

```
 Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copydoc = new PdfCopy(document, baos);
//some other codes here
 HashMap<String, Object> bookmark = new HashMap<>();
        bookmark.put("Title", toc_value);
        bookmark.put("Action", "GoTo");
        bookmark.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", entry.getKey()));
 outlines.add(bookmark);
//other codes here
 copydoc.setOutlines(outlines);
```

Please help me with this one.

Comment: Please share an example result file illustrating the issue.

Comment: Hi, This is a Highly shorted version of the actual PDF.Please download this in your local and open it in chrome or Adobe , you will see this is happening . [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XuDBbU69kqosaAtwb7Zh3y9rGikgtmFw/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: I get "access denied" for your link

Comment: can you please try again? There was permission issue. [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XuDBbU69kqosaAtwb7Zh3y9rGikgtmFw/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Ok, I could download the file now, but apparently you found out yourself how to fix and solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, Long story short I have found the solution to my issue. To explain the solution, let me explain what was written before.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, PdfReader> entry : filesToMerge.entrySet()) {
        n = entry.getValue().getNumberOfPages();
        toc.put(pageNo + 1, entry.getKey());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ) {
            pageNo++;
            page = copy.getImportedPage(entry.getValue(), ++i);
            stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);
            chunk = new Chunk(String.format("Page %d/ %d", pageNo+1,totalPage));
            if (i == 1)
                chunk.setLocalDestination("p" + pageNo);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(stamp.getUnderContent(),
                    Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase(chunk),
                    250, 10, 0);
            stamp.alterContents();
            copy.addPage(page);
        }
    }
```

Here , what I was doing , I was creating a `Chunk` which contains Page No. and alligning the chunk through `ColumnText` at the bottom of the page.My understanding is that this is the issue. So, when clicking on TOC links, it takes to bottom of the page and page is not fitting to window.

To resolve this I have added a Blank Text filled `Chunck` somewhere around the top of the page. And adding it as `LocalDestination`. Here is the updated code:

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, PdfReader> entry : filesToMerge.entrySet()) {
        n = entry.getValue().getNumberOfPages();
        toc.put(pageNo + 1, entry.getKey());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ) {
            pageNo++;
            page = copy.getImportedPage(entry.getValue(), ++i);
            stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);
            chunkBlank = new Chunk(" ");
            chunk = new Chunk(String.format("Page %d/ %d", pageNo+1,totalPage));
            if (i == 1) {
                chunk.setLocalDestination("p" + pageNo);
                chunkBlank.setLocalDestination( "p"+pageNo );
                }
            ColumnText.showTextAligned( stamp.getOverContent(),Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,new Phrase(chunkBlank),20,1000,0 );
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(stamp.getUnderContent(),
                    Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase(chunk),
                    250, 10, 0);
            stamp.alterContents();
            copy.addPage(page);
        }
    }
```